# Using Axios to retry request after refreshing JWT token in Vuex store

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework, axios, jwt, vuex

I'm trying to use Axios to retry failed requests due to JWT expiry

So far I have then following request in a method on a Vue component:

```
  getAPI2.get("/api/v1/sessions/",{ headers: headers }).then(response => {
          console.log(response);
          this.items = response.data.items;
      });
```

This is using the below interceptor when it hits an error

```
const getAPI2 = axios.create({
  baseURL: '/'
})


getAPI2.interceptors.response.use(response => response, err => {
  if (err.config && err.response && err.response.status === 401) {
    store.dispatch('refreshToken')
      .then(access => {

        axios.request({
          method: 'get',
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${store.state.accessToken}` },
          url: err.config.url
        }).then(response => {
          console.log('Successfully got data')
          console.log(response)
          return response;
        }).catch(err => {
          console.log('Got the new access token but errored after')
          return Promise.reject(err)
        })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        return Promise.reject(err)
      })
  }
})
```

I'm seeing the data when the request hits an error and goes through the interceptor but I think there's an issue in passing back the response to my component

Apologies if this is obvious, my javascript knowledge is in its infancy

Comment: Could you elaborate on `passing back the response to my component`? I don't really see any code in your question that would do that automatically for you. You may want to set some sort of flag in the store called `retryFailed` or `retrySucceeded` and then have the component use that. These flags would be set in the inner `then` block of the interceptor.

Comment: Actually, to modify my previous suggestion, I just noticed the interceptor is not in the store. The store should probably handle setting those flags in the refreshToken action that you kick off with `store.dispatch('refreshToken')`.

Comment: Thanks, I think maybe I've misunderstood what the interceptor should do, I thought that it would catch the error and then return the successful response after calling 'refreshToken'

Comment: Admittedly, axios may handle interceptors differently than I expected. I just checked the docs and realized you may be able to do what you were trying to do with them. However, another thing I noticed is you may have forgotten to put `return` in front of `store.dispatch('refreshToken')`. That's one of the most common beginner errors with promises (forgetting to return them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some playing around I managed to get this working:

```
const getAPI3 = axios.create({
  baseURL: '/'
})

  getAPI3.interceptors.response.use( (response) => {
    // Return normal response
    return response;
  }, (error) => {
    // Return non auth error
    if (error.response.status !== 401) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        reject(error);
      });
    }

    return store.dispatch('refreshToken')
      .then((token) => {

        // Make new request
        const config = error.config;
        config.headers = { Authorization: `Bearer ${store.state.accessToken}` }

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          axios.request(config).then(response => {
            resolve(response);
          }).catch((error) => {
            reject(error);
          })
        });

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        Promise.reject(error);
      });
  });
```